# SSH PermitLocalCommand - ! command produces no output

Tags: ssh

I've enabled PermitLocalCommand in my ssh .config file and I can run a command locally but the command I run appears to produce no output.

```
[local@localhost.com]$ ssh a@b.com
[a@b.com ~]$ echo "I'm on remote machine"
I'm on remote machine
~C
ssh> ! echo hello world

[a@b.com ~]$
```

I've no idea where the output goes...
I've tried doing `! echo hello world > /tmp/file` and I can see that the file does contain "hello world" so the actual command is being executed.

Does anyone know how I can get the output from the command to appear?